# Change the order of index in pandas DataFrame with multiindex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, reindex

I am trying to find a straightforward way to change the order of values in a pandas DatafFrame multiindex. To illustrate what I mean, suppose we have a DataFrame with multiindex define as follows:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[u'C', u'D', u'M'], [u'C', u'D', u'M']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=[u'level0', u'level1'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(9,3)),index=index,columns=['C','M','D'])
```

So we have a DataFrame df as follows:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to change the sequence of the Multiindex from "C D M" (which is ordered alphabetically) to "C M D" in both level0 and level1. I have tried to use pd.reindex, but have not found an easy way to achieve this goal.

Jezrael gave an answer below which gives the correct display:

```
L = list('CMD')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([L, L], names=df.index.names)
df = df.reindex(mux)
print (df)
```

However, what I need is that the levels of the index are in the order of "C M D" as well. If we check df.index, we get the following:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'C', u'D', u'M'], [u'C', u'D', u'M']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1]],
           names=[u'level0', u'level1'])
```

Note the "levels" are still in the order of "C D M". What I want is such that when I use df.unstack(), I still get the index in the order of "C M D". Sorry for not making this clear.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by new [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
np.random.seed(2018)
index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[u'C', u'D', u'M'], [u'C', u'D', u'M']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=[u'level0', u'level1'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(9,3)),
                  index=index,columns=['C','M','D'])
print (df)
               C  M  D
level0 level1         
C      C       6  2  9
       D       5  4  6
       M       9  9  7
D      C       9  6  6
       D       1  0  6
       M       5  6  7
M      C       0  7  8
       D       7  9  4
       M       8  1  2
```

---

```
L = list('CMD')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([L, L], names=df.index.names)
df = df.reindex(mux)
print (df)
               C  M  D
level0 level1         
C      C       6  2  9
       M       9  9  7
       D       5  4  6
M      C       0  7  8
       M       8  1  2
       D       7  9  4
D      C       9  6  6
       M       5  6  7
       D       1  0  6
```

EDIT:

If need set ordering create [ordered CategoricalIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#categorical-index) and then simply [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
L = pd.CategoricalIndex(list('CDM'), ordered=True, categories=list('CMD'))
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([L, L], names=df.index.names)
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
               C  M  D
level0 level1         
C      C       6  2  9
       M       9  9  7
       D       5  4  6
M      C       0  7  8
       M       8  1  2
       D       7  9  4
D      C       9  6  6
       M       5  6  7
       D       1  0  6
```

Check [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for new ordering:

```
print (df.unstack())
        C        M        D      
level1  C  M  D  C  M  D  C  M  D
level0                           
C       6  9  5  2  9  4  9  7  6
M       0  8  7  7  1  9  8  2  4
D       9  5  1  6  6  0  6  7  6
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response--really appreciate it. I do have another issue that is not solved by this method. I have edited the question. Sorry for not making may goal clear.